# Azure in-role cache as NHibernate second level cache?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, caching, azure

Is it possible to use Azure in-role cache as second level cache for NHibernate?

Since I'm quite new to both Azure development and NHibernate caching, I don't really know what to look for. Is there any tutorials, guides or similar describing this?

I'm about to start developing an Azure based application where there would be many clients reading data from the database (web and phone apps), but only one client writing data to it (both ways of course through appropriate web services).

At this moment I don't really know if caching would be needed, but in order not to paint myself into a corner, I would like to know that it is possible to add caching later if needed.

My idea is that when NHibernate on one instance writes to the cache, NHibernate on another instance (of the same role, sharing the same cache) could read this data from the cache, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it should be possible to implement your own second level cache provider for NHibernate by implementing `NHibernate.Cache.ICacheProvider`. Every cache provider supports NHibernate Query Cache and is compatible with every concurrency strategy (read-only, nonstrict-read-write, and read-write). But it is not easy, can take long time depending on how experienced developer you are and how well you know NHibernate. So I won't advice to do it, especially when you says that you don't know if you'll need it.

> My idea is that when NHibernate on one instance writes to the cache, NHibernate on another instance (of the same role, sharing the same cache) could read this data from the cache, or have I misunderstood something?

I would typically recommend using our [IIS Application Request Routing (ARR) module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to implement sticky session if they are required for the application. There are several resources describing this solution, here are a few interesting links:

- [Using the Application Request Routing Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module) : this is the standard installation documentation from the IIS team, that you could for example follow to deploy ARR on Windows Virtual Machines.
- The excellent [Richard Astbury](http://coderead.wordpress.com) from Two10Degrees has an [AzureARR project hosted on Github](https://github.com/richorama/AzureARR) that packages ARR in a Web Role for use in Cloud Services.

Comment: I don't think sticky session would help in this case.There would typically be one client sending data to the application, data which I would like to cache since all the other (hopefully thousands of) clients (connected to the same or other instances) would need that data. The reason would like to share the same cache (instead of instance specific caches) is to prevent clients connected to "other" instances to get stale data from the cache.